# Firebase always returning null for photoURL

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I've implemented Google login with Firebase Auth in Swift.

If I print out `imageUrl` here:

```
private func authenticateUser(for user: GIDGoogleUser?, with error: Error?) {
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }
    
    guard let user = user, let idToken = user.idToken?.tokenString else { return }
    
    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken, accessToken: user.accessToken.tokenString)
    
    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { [unowned self] (_, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            print(user.profile?.imageURL(withDimension: 36)?.absoluteString) // This works
        }
    }
}
```

This prints out the profile URL no problem.

But after authentication is successful and I call this in my view:

```
private var user = Auth.auth().currentUser

print(user?.photoURL?.absoluteString ?? "")
```

`photoURL` is always null here. Even though `user?.email` returns just fine.

What's wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: i tried it on my side and it working properly so, can you tell me the `Firebase` version which you are using?

Answer (score 0):

i am using `Firebase 10.8.0` try this way.

```
private var user = FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().currentUser
print(user?.photoURL?.absoluteString ?? "")
```